# Questions on directory on shell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

Say I make a directory using mkdir like this:
temp/king/learning 1

And I want to delete the folder learning 1 by using rmdir

But it gives me an error message, possibly because of the space between learning and 1. How do I delete this folder without getting an error message?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Place the directory name in quotes.

```
C:\> rd "temp\king\learning 1"
```

The quotes are not a part of the path name, but tell the command-line parser that the string between the quotes is a single string. Without the quotes, you are giving the `rd` (same as `rmdir`) command two separate parameters.